# insertAdjacentHTML() doesn't insert portfolio item into portfolio list using an onload function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, dom

Using a 'food' table from a mySQL database, I plan to GET the values from it and display them in a portfolio. When I attempt this, however, only my portfolio filter appears on my website. I've stored the displayFoods() function in a separate .js file and am referencing it in my index.html file.

Using console.log, I've determined that displayFoods() is indeed being called using onload in my body tag and my values are being loaded in correctly. I'm not sure about the HTML code that I'm trying to insert. Any help in resolving this issue would be appreciated, thanks!

The onload function:

```
function displayFoods() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open("GET", food_url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.onload = function() {
    // We create a 'foods' variable to store data of all foods retrieved  
    // from the server.
    // All foods will be stored in the form of an array in the foods variable.
        var foods = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

        var totalFoods = foods.length;
        console.log(totalFoods);
        // Get the HTML element of the div where id="foodlist" so that
        // we can add HTML codes to display all the foods.
        var listings = document.getElementById("foodlist");

        // We use a for loop to traverse through the array of foods.
        // For every food, we get the name, info, foodType, price, pictureSmall and pictureLarge. 
        for (var count = 0; count < totalFoods; count++) {
            var name = foods[count].name;
            var info = foods[count].info;
            var foodType = foods[count].foodType;
            var price = foods[count].price;
            var pictureSmall = foods[count].pictureSmall;
            var pictureLarge = foods[count].pictureLarge;

            console.log(count);
            console.log(name);
            console.log(info);
            console.log(foodType);
            console.log(price);
            console.log(pictureSmall);
            console.log(pictureLarge);

            // We create the HTML codes for displaying each food and store in a variable 'foodItem'.
            // We also insert each food value (name, info, etc.) in the HTML codes. 
            var foodItem = 
                  '<div class="portfolio-item '+foodType+' col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> \
                    <div class="recent-work-wrap"> \
                      <img class="img-responsive" src="'+pictureSmall+'" alt=""> \
                      <div class="overlay"> \
                        <div class="recent-work-inner"> \
                          <h3> \
                            <a href="#">'+name+'</a> \
                          </h3> \
                           <p>'+info+' \
                            <br>$'+price+'0</p> \
                          <a class="preview" href="'+pictureLarge+'" rel="prettyPhoto"> \
                            <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</a> \
                        </div> \
                      </div> \
                    </div> \
                  </div>';

            console.log(foodItem);

            // We use the built-in JavaScript function insertAdjacentHTML() which is from 
            // the HTML element object to insert the HTML codes.                  
            listings.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', foodItem);
        }
    };

    // Send the request to get info of all foods.
    request.send();
}
```

Portfolio code attempting to use displayFoods():

```
<section id="portfolio">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="center">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <h2>Menu</h2>
        <hr>
        <p class="lead">Take a look at our selects!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <ul class="portfolio-filter text-center">
        <li>
          <a class="btn btn-default active" href="#" data-filter="*">All Items</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".alacarte">A la carte</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".drinks">Drinks</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".desserts">Desserts</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!--/#portfolio-filter-->

      <div class="row">
        <div class="portfolio-items">
          <div id="foodlist"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Hardcoded portfolio code:

```
<section id="portfolio">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="center">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <h2>Menu</h2>
        <hr>
        <p class="lead">Take a look at our selects!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <ul class="portfolio-filter text-center">
        <li>
          <a class="btn btn-default active" href="#" data-filter="*">All Items</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".alacarte">Sandwiches</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".drinks">Drinks</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".desserts">Desserts</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!--/#portfolio-filter-->

      <div class="row">
        <div class="portfolio-items">


          <!--/.portfolio-item-->

          <div class="portfolio-item alacarte col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <div class="recent-work-wrap">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="images/portfolio/recent-new/hamncheese.png" alt="">
              <div class="overlay">
                <div class="recent-work-inner">
                  <h3>
                    <a href="#">Ham and Cheese Sandwich</a>
                  </h3>
                  <p>Ham, Cheese, Brioche Bread
                    <br>$1</p>
                  <a class="preview" href="images/portfolio/full-new/hamncheese.png" rel="prettyPhoto">
                    <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!--/.portfolio-item-->

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!--/#portfolio-item-->
```

.portfolio-item over here is repeated two more times with different values from my food table, so I'll cut it out here.

listFoods.html code:
This is a .html file with the js script also included, all in one file. It works fine, but it doesn't use a portfolio.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>List Foods</title>
    <style>
        .grid-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
            background-color: #2196F3;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .grid-item {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
            padding: 20px;
            font-size: 30px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function displayFoods() {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

            // The route pattern '/movies' is registered in the routeMovies.js file.
            request.open("GET", "/food", true);
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.onload = function() {
                // We create a 'movies' variable to store data of all movies retrieved  
                // from the server.
                // All movies will be stored in the form of an array in the movies variable.
                var foods = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

                var totalFoods = foods.length;
                // Get the HTML element of the div where id="movieListings" so that
                // we can add HTML codes to display all the movies.
                var listings = document.getElementById("foodListings");

                // We use a for loop to traverse through the array of movies.
                // For every movie, we get the name and picture. 
                for (var count = 0; count < totalFoods; count++) {
                    var name = foods[count].name;
                    var pictureSmall = foods[count].pictureSmall;
                    var pictureLarge = foods[count].pictureLarge;
                    var foodType = foods[count].foodType;
                    var info = foods[count].info;
                    var price = foods[count].price;

                    // We create the HTML codes for displaying each movie and store in a variable 'movieItem'.
                    // We also insert each movie name and picture in the HTML codes. 
                    var foodItem = '<div class="grid-item">                \
                        <img src="' + pictureSmall + '">       \
                        <h3>' + name + '</h3>              \
                     </div>';

                    // We use the built-in JavaScript function insertAdjacentHTML() which is from 
                    // the HTML element object to insert the HTML codes.                  
                    listings.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', foodItem);
                }
            };

            // Send the request to get info of all movies.
            request.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<!-- When this page loads, execute the JavaScript displayMovies() function that we created above. -->

<body onload="displayFoods()">
    <!-- We create a div element that will display the list of movies. -->
    <!-- We use a CSS class 'grid-container' that we create in this page to organise the display. -->
    <div id="foodListings" class="grid-container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

[console.log(foodItem); result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdWYN.png)

Thanks again!

Comment: Your problem is not clear.. what happens when you run this?

Comment: @dasacodec When I use the displayFoods() attempt html code, only my portfolio filter bar appears on my website, but unlike in the hardcoded version, the portfolio items do not appear.

Comment: try something like this  listings.innerHTML += foodItem instead of insertAdjacentHTML\

Comment: @dasacodec Doesn't work either.

Comment: show me your console.log(foodItem) result

Comment: @dasacodec I've edited my post to add an image of it at the end.

Comment: I tryed to recreate an issue in [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/oEBJdP?editors=1011) by avoiding the Ajax request... And it seems to work. The issue must be elsewhere...

Comment: From your `console.log(foodItem);` printscreen... I notice a lot of white spaces, which should not be there. Are you sure you used the `\ `  to avoid concatening those and the line feeds? You could also try to close the quotes and use `+` to concatenate... Check that! ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I added '\'s at the end of every line in foodItem (inside "The onload function" code in the post), though I'm not sure if there needs to be any additional spacing too. If so, could you please enlighten me on that? I'll try using +'ses to concatenate for now.

Comment: If you are sure to use the '\'s... Maybe you have a caching problem. Try to clear it and retry. Since the JS is in an external file, it may be cached, so you may be using an old version without the '\'s... Try [ctrl]+[F5]

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Nah, CTRL-F5 didn't really change anything.

Comment: Okay... Do you have a live link?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette No, unfortunately. I'm only able to host it locally.

Comment: I have no other idea...

Comment: Alright, I've tried removing the portfolio entirely and just inserting my values. It worked fine, so it looks like there's some issue with using insertAdjacentHTML() for a portfolio item.

Comment: Ha! so the issue is about the values... Check for a single quote! That is possibly an apostrophe. If so, use double quotes for concatenation and escape the one for the tag attributes, like this: `"<a href=\"#\">"+name+"</a>" +`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Looks like the problem wasn’t with the quotes. I’ve looked around my files and it looks like my bootstrap screws it up somehow. I’ve decided to just remove the portfolio filter and just display the items to save time, since this is for an assignment that’s due very soon. Thanks for your help, though!